# Ant Design Table - Filtering by Date Range

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I've trying to implement a date range filter in my Ant Design's table using this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60206765/react-js-ant-design-range-filter-with-start-and-end-dates-error) but no success so far.
It looks like isn't working on newer versions of Ant Design.

Someone had successfully implemented it? How?

Comment: "No success so far" does not tell us much. Include a codepen or maybe a part of code you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

1. Find filterDropdown method in https://ant.design/components/table/#header
2. Replace <Input ... > with:

   <DatePicker.RangePicker
   style={{ marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
   value={selectedKeys[0]}
   onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e ? [e] : [])}
   onPressEnter={() => {
   confirm();
   setSearchText(selectedKeys[0]),
   setSearchedColumn(dataIndex);
   }}
   />
3. Replace onFilter with:

   onFilter: (value, record) => record[dataIndex] ?
   moment(record[dataIndex]).isBetween(value[0], value[1], 'day', '[]') : "" ,
4. (optionally) replace render with:

   render: text => moment(text).format("DD/MM/YYYY")

Comment: Unfortunately what wouldn't work. Seems like Table filter doesn't support AND logic and provides filter values one by one to onFilter function:
https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/table/hooks/useFilter/index.tsx#L160

Answer (score 0):

community,

I don't know If you could resolve it, but I did with this code and it worked.

I added this code in colums:

```
 filters: [],filteredValue: filteredInfo.dateRange ? [filteredInfo.dateRange.startDate, filteredInfo.dateRange.endDate] : null,
 onFilter: (value, record) => {
 const { vaccineDate } = record;
 const { startDate, endDate } = filteredInfo.dateRange;
 return moment(vaccineDate).isBetween(startDate, endDate, null, '[]');
```

I did a lot of tests to find this solution.